# How to pass the boundfield value to a label in the same page?

Tags: asp.net, eval, detailsview

In my aspx page, I have a detailsView and a label. The label's text should show the same value as a boundfield of the detailsview. How do I get both of them populated at the same time?
Following is my apsx page, I tried the Eval, it didn't work. I don't want to do it in the code-behind.

```
        <tr>
    <td > <asp:label runat="server" text='<%# Eval("ReporterName")%>'/></td>
        </tr>

<tr>
<td>
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" >

    <Fields>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="sprID" HeaderText="SPRID" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="sprID" >
        <HeaderStyle Width="230px" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="Product" 
            SortExpression="ProductName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DivisionName" HeaderText="Technology Group" 
            SortExpression="DivisionName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DisciplineName" HeaderText="Discipline" 
            SortExpression="DisciplineName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ReporterName" HeaderText="Reporter" 
            SortExpression="ReporterName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="OwnerName" HeaderText="Owner" 
            SortExpression="OwnerName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="SalesLeadName" HeaderText="SalesLead" 
            SortExpression="SalesLeadName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="RegionName" HeaderText="Region" 
            SortExpression="RegionName" />

    </Fields>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `DataBound` event, like this:

```
protected void DetailsView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = DataBinder.Eval(DetailsView1.DataItem, "SomeValue").ToString();
}
```